# Confused about Ember Data 1.13 Serializing for sideloaded data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I had stepped away from ember for a bit and I've recently come back to the 1.13 release with Ember-Data 1.13. I was initially excited about the new JSON API formatting, as I thought that it would easily support sideloaded records, as per the example given in the change docs.

```
{
  data: { 
    id: '1', 
    type: 'user', 
    attributes: {
      name: 'wecc'
    }, 
    relationships: {
      accounts: {
        data: [
          { id: '1', type: 'account' },
          { id: '2', type: 'account' }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  included: [{ 
    id: '1',
    type: 'account',
    attributes: {
      email: 'wecc@sweden.se'
    }
  }, {
    id: '2',
    type: 'account',
    attributes: {
      email: 'wecc@greece.gr'
    }
  }]
}
```

It was my understanding that if I normalized the payload to the above then it would handle my relationships for me and create the records in the store. It seems this is not the case, and I was hoping someone could explain what I must do in order to properly create the records in the store.

To be clear this is the code that I'm running from my controller,

```
getData: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.store.findRecord("user", 1).then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.get('name'));
    console.log(self.store.peekAll('account'));
  });

}
```

And I'm expecting the peekAll to show me two records but it doesn't. Logging user and user.get('name') does work. Thanks!

UPDATE:
Now I'm getting a console error `Cannot read property '_internalModel' of undefined` whenever I try to load it. This is in the function

```
function _find(adapter, store, typeClass, id, internalModel, options) {
  var snapshot = internalModel.createSnapshot(options);
  var promise;
  if (!adapter.findRecord) {
    Ember.deprecate("Adapter#find has been deprecated and renamed to `findRecord`.");
    promise = adapter.find(store, typeClass, id, snapshot);
  } else {
    promise = adapter.findRecord(store, typeClass, id, snapshot);
  }
  var serializer = serializerForAdapter(store, adapter, internalModel.type.modelName);
  var label = "DS: Handle Adapter#find of " + typeClass + " with id: " + id;

  promise = Promise.cast(promise, label);
  promise = _guard(promise, _bind(_objectIsAlive, store));

  return promise.then(function (adapterPayload) {
    Ember.assert("You made a request for a " + typeClass.typeClassKey + " with id " + id + ", but the adapter's response did not have any data", adapterPayload);
    return store._adapterRun(function () {
      var requestType = get(serializer, "isNewSerializerAPI") ? "findRecord" : "find";
      var payload = normalizeResponseHelper(serializer, store, typeClass, adapterPayload, id, requestType);
      //TODO Optimize
      var record = pushPayload(store, payload);
      return record._internalModel;
    });
  }, function (error) {
    internalModel.notFound();
    if (internalModel.isEmpty()) {
      internalModel.unloadRecord();
    }

    throw error;
  }, "DS: Extract payload of '" + typeClass + "'");
}
```

Also for reference here are the models I'm using (I've tried with and without embedded always)

```
var User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  accounts: DS.hasMany('account', {embedded: 'always'})
});
var Account = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this may be the cause, but did you set {async: false} for those relationships?

Comment: No, but I also didn't set {async: true}. I am seeing the request go through to the server, as well as come back with the data, it just isn't pushing my accounts into the store.

Comment: With ember-data 1.13 {embedded: 'always'} on relationship won't have any effect as it is not a valid option (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.html#method_hasMany). You should try EmbeddedRecordsMixin in your adapter: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that Ember 1.13 handled it without me specifying. However I'm unable to test whether that will work because I'm now getting the `Cannot read property '_internalModel' of undefined` error

Comment: @jake-dluhy I am also facing same error. Are you able to get it work? Can you please add the details or answer. It would be very helpful.. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `JSONAPIAdapter` and `JSONAPISerializer`? Ember may not be defaulting to those.